# Python matplotlib plots empty graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

What's wrong with my code? I'm not sure why its not plotting the results in the plot.  It is only displaying an empty plot, am I missing a step?

```
failure_rate = 0.0005
gyro_tot=4
start = 1
R_sum = 0
# t = symbols('t')
# R = np.exp(-failure_rate*t)
# R_t = lambda t: R

for t in range (0,20000):
    R_sum = 0
    for i in range(0,3):
        R = np.exp(-failure_rate*t)
        R_func = pow(R,i+1)
        CDF_dist = pow((1 - R),gyro_tot-(start+i))
        C = combinations_without_repetition(gyro_tot,3)
        R_func = C*R_func*CDF_dist
        R_sum = R_sum + R_func

    datafr={'time':[t], 'reliability':[R_sum]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(datafr)
    print(df)

plt.xlim(0,20000)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.plot(t,R_sum)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that `R_sum` is a scalar?

Comment: @Isotope yes it is scalar. but there is an R_sum value for each timestamp (that's what the nested for-loop does) and I was able to print them using pd.DataFrame.. I'm just struggling with the plot, somethings wrong..

Comment: I think I understand your problem. Maybe try to print `t` and `R_sum` just before your the line `plt.plot(t,R_sum)`. So insert `print(R_sum)` above the `plot` function call. What is it showing you?

Comment: @Isotope still got an empty plot

Comment: Yes, obviously a `print` statement does not change the plot. I am trying to help you debugging your code. Now, what was the output of that new line?

Comment: So the code above gives me a new value of R_sum for each timestamp. When I moved the print function outside the loop, I only got the final value of R_sum with its timestamp (a single scalar value). Could it be the way I defined the plot lines wrong?

Comment: Yes, very much so. I think you are overwriting your `R_sum` in the inner loop. What you might want to do is create lists of `R_sum` and `t`. Otherwise you will just plot a single point which might not be visible. I would go about and define a list outside the loop and than append the `R_sum` values in the loop to the list.

Comment: YES, you were right! That worked!!! Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome :)